# gdal_viewshed for target above sea level

Tags: python, gis, gdal

I'm trying to compute some terrain visibility analysis on DEM data by using GDAL library.
The gdal_viewshed worked in the case of target  Above Ground Level (AGL).
Is there any way to use this routine also for the case: target Above Sea Level (ASL)? or are there any other routines that do it ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Call `gdallocationinfo` on the DEM dataset, get the value and then call `gdal_viewshed` with the difference of that value with your AMSL height.

If you want to use the `-mode` flag you will have to use `gdal_calc` on the result together with your DEM dataset to obtain the correct offset.